# Objective-C blocks in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I'm rewrite my Objective-C app into Swift, and facing a problem in convert this Objective-C code to Swift.

Objective-C Code:

```
for ( void(^block)(void) in enumerator.allObjects) {
    if (block)
        block();
}
```

Swift Code:

```
for (var block: () -> Void in enumerator.allObjects) {
        if (block) {
            block();
        }
    }
```

The Xcode shows 3 errors:

> Expected expression
>
> Expected condition in 'for' statement
>
> Expected ';' in 'for' statement

Thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: I thought Swift didn't need trailing semicolons...

Comment: @TravisGriggs Yes, me neither. Maybe it is the compiler's error.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the parentheses

```
  1> for i in 1...3 {
  2.     println(i) 
  3. } 
1
2
3
  4> for (i in 1...3) {
  5.     println(i) 
  6. } 
repl.swift:4:8: error: expected ';' in 'for' statement
for (i in 1...3) {
       ^
repl.swift:4:8: error: expected condition in 'for' statement
for (i in 1...3) {
       ^
repl.swift:4:8: error: expected ';' in 'for' statement
for (i in 1...3) {
       ^
repl.swift:4:8: error: expected expression
for (i in 1...3) {
       ^
repl.swift:4:8: error: expected ')' in 'for' statement
for (i in 1...3) {
       ^
repl.swift:4:5: note: to match this opening '('
for (i in 1...3) {
    ^
repl.swift:4:8: error: expected '{' in 'for' statement
for (i in 1...3) {
       ^
repl.swift:4:18: error: statement cannot begin with a closure expression
for (i in 1...3) {
                 ^
repl.swift:4:18: note: explicitly discard the result of the closure by assigning to '_'
for (i in 1...3) {
                 ^
                 _ = 
repl.swift:4:18: error: braced block of statements is an unused closure
for (i in 1...3) {
                 ^

  4>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
let block1 : (Int)->() = { i in
    println(i)
}
let block2 : (Int)->() = { i in
    println(i*2)
}

let array = [block1, block2]

for block in array {
    block(1)
}
```